# PowerShell, hash table: add objects?

Tags: powershell, hash

I need to open several objects: two sockets each with a `Stream` and a `Writer`, one pipe with...

Can I store them in hashes so that I just call a function with a hash and in that function I can access the specific socket, stream, or writer?

How do I predefine this hash-entry?

```
 $hash = @{
   ...
   "Socket" = ???
   "Stream" = ???
   "Writer" = ???
 ...
 }

 function connect {
    param([hashtable] $h)
    try {
        $Enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII
        $h.Socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient $h.IP, $h.PORT
        $h.Stream = $h.Socket.GetStream() # Or better: $($h.Socket).GetStream()
        $h.Writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($h.Stream, $Enc)
        ...
    }
    catch { ...}
    ...
 }
```

And the use of all that:

```
 function WriteMsg {
     param([hashtable]]$h, [string]]$m)
     try {
        $h.Writer.Write($m) #
     }
     catch {
        Write-Host $_ #Write-Debug $_
     }
 }
```

Would that be saved to use?

PS:

For those who might be interested, this seems to work - so far:

```
$Conn1 = New-Object psobject -Property @{
     "ID"     = "Conn1"
     "State"  = "ok"

     "IP"     = "127.0.0.1"
     "PORT"   = 4711
     "Socket" = $Null
     "Stream" = $Null
     "Writer" = $Null
}

function conn { # Usage: conn $Conn1
     param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [PSObject] $h
    )
     try {
          $e = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII
          $h.Socket = $(New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient $h.IP, $h.PORT)
          if ($h.Socket.Connected) {
                $h.Stream = $($h.Socket.GetStream())
                $h.Writer = $(New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter( $h.Stream, $e))
                $h.Writer.AutoFlush = $true
          }
     }
     catch {
        Write-Host "$($h.ID) Connection Failed $_" #Write-Debug $_
    }
    finally {
        return
    }
}
```

Even a re-new of the connection won't fail due to a double entry.

Comment: Do you try it ? Do you met some troubles ?

Comment: You could use a PSObject object instead of a hashtable. IMO hashtables are more suitable for storing larger data sets that would make sense as a table.

Comment: @JPBlac: not yet tried, I am still 'concepting' what already works with  1 socket, strean, writer for multiple connections without using multiple threads..

Comment: @Alex. Obersth  I'll have a look at it, thanks.
If hastables were suitable for larger data sets would PSObject be faster for only a few (20) entries?

Comment: @gooly, performance differences would be negligible here. But IMHO a custom object is much nicer than misusing hash tables as objects with properties. You can use `New-Object PSObject -Prop @{ ... }` to create one.

Comment: @Joey Thanks, I did what you suggested, see the bottom of my post (for others too)